# Why don't mmorpgs use bots?

Tags: npc

Bots in games can bad and usefull depending on the genre.

A lot of small games use bots to create a fake player base and illude the player that he is playing with real people.

The scariest thing is, that in most of these games you can't actually tell if you are playing with/against real people or bots and sometimes in shooter games bots can be way better than real people, not because they have more HP or more damage, they are not rpgs but shooter games.

And in chatting simulator games, where you actually speak to bots... Some are trashy but a few can get creative , these bots get to the point where they feel like real people... Or at least it means in my life I have encountered people that act like robots.

But there's only one genre of games where bots are not only useful but might be essential.

Rpg's

Why? Immersion. 
What's the point of playing a game with an epic giant world twice the size of the real earth if the player base is a few millions (at best) ? You are gonna feel extremely lonely when exploring or you are not in a raid/battleground/dungeon.

most mmos I've explored tend to have really beautiful empy and soulless landscapes and cities... Entire cities with maybe only 30 npcs inside...

And npcs don't do anything, they are different from bots.

Bots try to replicate human behavior, they can talk with you help or try to kill you.

In some games as I have already said bots are created to make the illusion of multi-player but in mmorpgs you already know there are npcs and not every character you encounter is a person but limiting npcs to being statues that stand still in a city to sell you endless items is a waste of pure potential.

So why don't mmos use bots when lesser games can do it perfectly and make their bots seem real? What's the drawback?

Comment: If you are interested in implementing bots to simulate population in the MMO you are developing, do so - it doesn't matter what other games have or haven't done or why they made that choice. If you've run into any particular difficulty designing or implementing your bots to achieve your goals, you can ask here for help solving that problem. If you're *not* interested in implementing bots in your own game, then this question may not be on-topic here. This StackExchange is for answering questions related to developing an original game or mod, not speculating about decisions in existing games.

Comment: Cost may be one factor. A shooter game probably already has AI from the single player mode (or a previous version had single player) that can be re-used for fake online players. While MMOs will likely not have human-like AI sitting around to re-use and there won't be much incentive to put resources towards developing it when additional content is far more likely to translate into more profit.

Comment: I agree with DMGregory, that this question does not fit the Q&A format of this site since it involves too much speculation about design decisions. However, to give you a reason: Development time. MMORPGs are probably the most challenging type of game you can develop. So your team is already quite busy. A convincing bot needs to act like a human player. While this is "easy" in a simple shooter, were everything you can do is moving and shooting, the complexity rises quickly with the options a player has and an MMO has tons of it.